# Verb: Using an item of a subscription with limited items included

Tags: verbs

Let's imagine that you buy a subscription ... for example, to get 2 Yoga lessons per month. What would be the right verb if I am using one of these lessons?

I am considering using something like 'redeem' or 'check-in'. What is the correct term for this? Would the teacher use the term check-in? While the student would use redeem (like redeem a voucher)?

Comment: What do you find in dictionaries for "redeem"? If you consult them and still have difficulty, please come back and ask.

Comment: Probably 'use one of my two monthly slots / lessons'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Edwin: *use*, or perhaps *make use of*. For something more formal in tone (and probably more suitable for writing) you can use the verb **avail**:

> **avail oneself of** *or less commonly* **avail of**
>
> To make use of: to take advantage of
>
> *They availed themselves of his services.* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/avail)

> **avail oneself of**
>
> In American English
>
> To take advantage of (an opportunity, etc.); utilize [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/avail-yourself-of)

> Phrasal Verbs
> **avail of**
>
> *mainly formal*
> (**avail oneself of something or avail of something**)
> Use or take advantage of an opportunity or available resource.
>
> *My daughter did not avail herself of my advice.*
>
> *Students in the district avail of the free meal scheme in schools.*[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/avail)

---

> Submit your membership application and **avail yourself** these
> benefits at extremely low cost...and command with confidence. [*Army*,
> Vol. 14](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Army/7zxEAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=submit%20your%20membership%20application) (1963)

> In addition to the History of Eclecticism subscribers **can avail
> themselves** of the following offers:
> ...
> None but our paid-up
> subscribers can **avail themselves** of this offer. [*The Medical
> Tribune*, Vol. 7](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Medical_Tribune/gb81-882pZ4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=subscribers%20can%20avail%20themselves%20of&pg=PA121&printsec=frontcover) p.121 (1891)

> A privilege grants me (in principle) an opportunity. I have no duty to
> **avail myself of** it, and even if I do (or try to), ... [Constance Putnam; *Hospice or Hemlock*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Hospice_Or_Hemlock/GmFwa3I7vqMC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=availed%20myself%20of%20subscription%20privileges&pg=PA78&printsec=frontcover) (2002)

> If you have been extended an honorary membership in an organization
> and you **avail yourself of** the privileges, rights, etc., to a
> substantial degree, and the dues are in excess of $250 a year, you
> must report the honorary membership in this Part. [*Impeachment Trial
> Committee on the Articles Against Judge ...*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Impeachment_Trial_Committee_on_the_Artic/XFlRAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=avail%20yourself%20of%20subscription&pg=PA2274&printsec=frontcover) (2010)

> There are persons who because of geographic distance or national
> situation might find that they could not **avail themselves** readily
> of the full range of privileges of membership. [American Mathematical
> Society, *A History of the Second Fifty Years*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_history_of_the_second_fifty_years_Amer/JY3OxdP0h5cC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=avail%20yourself%20of%20membership%20privileges&pg=PA156&printsec=frontcover) (1998)

The examples without the "of" sound very strange to my American ears.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not know the word avail!